# Going from MagicalRecord to NSPersistentContainer. How to preserve data?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

On the currently live App Store application I am using MagicalRecord to setup my Core Data. As I was facing some issue with concurrency, I looked around for solution. I realised that since the introduction of iOS 10, Core Data has been simplified and I could use it directly without Magical Record.

**Magical Record Setup**

Using the latest repository and carthage, I use the following line to setup core data.

```
    MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(withAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed: "Model")
```

**NSPersistentContainer Setup**

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

**Problem**

It is like setting up a new database and I cannot access the data that were stored with the Magical Record setup.

I tried to see if MagicalRecord is making any changes to the name used and it looks like it does not. Does anyone know how to make the transition and still be able to access my old data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to correct the store URL as it is in a non-standard location.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")

    // Change from the default store location
    let url = .... where is your database?
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```